# Maximise $y$ with respect to $x$ for $y=\prod_{k=1}^{\infty}(1-x^{-k})$

Tags: sequences-and-series, derivatives, optimization, infinite-product

$$y=\prod_{k=1}^{\infty}(1-x^{-k})$$
I want to maximise this function. So far I have:
$$\ln(y)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\ln(1-x^{-k})$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}\cdot\frac{1}{y}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{kx^{-k-1}}{1-x^{-k}}$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}\cdot\frac{x}{y}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{kx^{-k}}{1-x^{-k}}$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}\cdot\frac{x}{y}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{k}{x^{k}-1}$$
For a turning point, $\frac{dy}{dx}=0$, therefore
$$0=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{k}{x^{k}-1}$$
Which I acknowledge is probably difficult to solve in any way other than numerically. That $x^k-1$ term has an $x-1$ factor, though I doubt that will help.

Comment: $\frac{dy}{dx}\cdot\frac{1}{y}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{kx^{-k-1}}{1-x^{-k}}$

Comment: Good catch.  I'll fix it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(x)=\prod_{k\geq 1}(1-x^k)$, defined over $I=(-1,1)$. We have:
$$\frac{d}{dx}\log f(x) = \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{d}{dx}\log(1-x^k)=-\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{k x^{k-1}}{1-x^k}=-\frac{1}{x}\sum_{n\geq 1}\sigma_1(n)\, x^n$$
where $\sigma_1(n)=\sum_{d\mid n}d$ is the sum-of-divisors function. To locate the maximum of $f(x)$, that occurs for some $x\in(-1,0)$, it is sufficient to solve with some numerical algorithm (for instance, Newton's method) the equation:
$$ 0 = \sum_{n\geq 1}\sigma_1(n)\,x^n. $$
We have that the real zero of the last equation is around $x\approx -0.41118$, so your function attains its maximum when $\color{red}{x\approx -2.432}$.

Comment: (+1) That is where I have been stuck :( Is there a way of approximating the solution to the final equation ?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something trivial here. Why are you assuming I am dealing with only the $(-1,0)$ range? Can't it be solved outside of that range?

Comment: @r9m: with Newton's method I got that the maximum of $f(x)$ occurs when $x\approx -0.41118$.

Comment: @nathan.j.mcdougall: outside that range the function is a product of positive monotonic functions, so there is little to locate.

Comment: Wolfram|Alpha suggests otherwise: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%3D+product+k%3D1+to+infinity+%281-x%5E-k%29

Comment: @nathan.j.mcdougall: otherwise what? WA says that your function is increasing over $(0,1)$. Also notice that I changed the variable from $x^{-1}$ to $x$, so my $f(x)$ is your function evaluated in $x^{-1}$.

Comment: That implies that the maximum of your function occurs at $x\approx -2.432$.

Comment: Oh! I see, that makes a lot of sense, thank you. I was a little confused as to what you had done, since I am unfamiliar with a lot of the notation.